# Compare two dataframes and create a report giving the fieldname and old/new values where there are differences

Tags: r, dataframe, compare

I have two dataframes, `df.old` and `df.new`. `df.old` contains extra columns that `df.new` does not hold. I would like to compare each individual cell in `df.new` with the cell related to the same row (same `ID_KEY`) column in `df.old`. I would then like to create a separate dataframe which is a report of all of the differences giving the `ID_KEY`, Fieldname and old and new values. For example:

```
df.old:
ID_KEY | Date of Valuation | Original LTV | Tenure | Valuation in Current Condition | Comment
1       22/02/2016         76%     Leasehold     £151,000
2       22/02/2016         75%     Leasehold     £151,000
3       23/02/2016         76%     Leasehold     £150,000
4       24/02/2016         76%     Freehold     £151,000

df.new:
ID_KEY | Date of Valuation | Original LTV | Tenure | Valuation in Current Condition
1       21/02/2016         76%     Leasehold     £151,000
2       22/02/2016         73%     Leasehold     £151,000
3       23/02/2016         76%     Leasehold     £153,000
4       24/02/2016         76%     Leasehold     £151,000
```

Report:

```
ID_KEY | Fieldname        |              df.old_value | df.new_value
1      Date of Valuation              22/02/2016   21/02/2016
2      Original LTV                   75%          73%
3      Valuation in Current Condition £150,000     £153,000
4      Tenure                         Freehold     Leasehold
```

I can manage to write this in VBA, but my R code is a bit rusty. I know there is an easier way to write this in R using split-apply-combine, but I am having trouble figuring it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** A possible approach is to `melt` the dataframes into long format, merge them and then filter them for non-matching values:

```
library(reshape2)

df.old2 <- melt(df.old, id.vars = "ID_KEY", value.name = "df.old_value")
df.new2 <- melt(df.new, id.vars = "ID_KEY", value.name = "df.new_value")

df.merged <- merge(df.old2, df.new2, by = c("ID_KEY","variable"))
df.merged[df.merged$df.old_value!=df.merged$df.new_value,]
```

which gives:

```
   ID_KEY                    variable df.old_value df.new_value
1       1           Date.of.Valuation   22/02/2016   21/02/2016
6       2                Original.LTV          75%          73%
12      3 Valuation.Current.Condition     £150,000     £153,000
15      4                      Tenure     Freehold    Leasehold
```

---

**Option 2:** An alternative is to `merge` the dataframes together first and then `melt` the result into long format with the enhanced `melt` function from the *data.table* package which is able to give multiple value columns in the output based on patterns:

```
# create a vector with the common fieldnames
fnames <- names(df.new)[-1]
# or:
fnames <- names(df.old)[names(df.old) %in% names(df.new)][-1]

# merge the dataframes together based on "ID_KEY"
df1 <- merge(df.old, df.new, by = "ID_KEY")

# melt 'df1' into long format and check where the two value columns don't match
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df1), "ID_KEY", 
     measure.vars = patterns(".x",".y"),
     variable.name = "fieldname",
     value.name = c("df.old_value","df.new_value"))[, fieldname := fnames[fieldname]
                                                    ][df.old_value!=df.new_value][]
```

which gives:

```
   ID_KEY                   fieldname df.old_value df.new_value
1:      1           Date.of.Valuation   22/02/2016   21/02/2016
2:      2                Original.LTV          75%          73%
3:      4                      Tenure     Freehold    Leasehold
4:      3 Valuation.Current.Condition     £150,000     £153,000
```

---

*NOTE*: I used data which also has a non-matching `ID_KEY` in `df.old`:

```
df.old <- read.table(text="ID_KEY  Date.of.Valuation  Original.LTV  Tenure  Valuation.Current.Condition  Comment
1       22/02/2016         76%     Leasehold     £151,000  Comment
2       22/02/2016         75%     Leasehold     £151,000  Comment
3       23/02/2016         76%     Leasehold     £150,000  Comment
4       24/02/2016         76%     Freehold     £151,000  Comment
5       24/02/2016         76%     Freehold     £151,000  Comment", header=TRUE)

df.new <- read.table(text="ID_KEY  Date.of.Valuation  Original.LTV  Tenure  Valuation.Current.Condition
1       21/02/2016         76%     Leasehold     £151,000
2       22/02/2016         73%     Leasehold     £151,000
3       23/02/2016         76%     Leasehold     £153,000
4       24/02/2016         76%     Leasehold     £151,000", header=TRUE)
```

---

***UPDATE FOR THE NEW EXAMPLE DATA:***

Applying the approach with *reshape2*:

```
df.old2 <- melt(df.old, id.vars = "Loan Identifier", value.name = "df.old_value")
df.new2 <- melt(df.new, id.vars = "Loan Identifier", value.name = "df.new_value")

df.m <- merge(df.old2, df.new2, by = c("Loan Identifier","variable"))
df.r <- df.m[which(df.m$df.old_value!=df.m$df.new_value),]
```

which gives:

```
> head(df.r)
   Loan Identifier                       variable df.old_value df.new_value
1        960959610 Advance Amount (Gross Advance)       172499       166000
8        960959610                Completion date   1446422400   1447286400
11       960959610                      Income B1        22800        47211
12       960959610                      Income B2        22000        19461
13       960959610                  Interest Rate       0.0309       0.0409
21       960959610                  Original Term          420          240
```

With *data.table* the approach used on the first example dataset does not work. A working solution similar to the *reshape2* method:

```
# making copies, not necessarily needed
df.o <- as.data.table(df.old)
df.n <- as.data.table(df.new)

df.o2 <- melt(df.o, id.vars = "Loan Identifier", value.name = "df.old_value")
df.n2 <- melt(df.n, id.vars = "Loan Identifier", value.name = "df.new_value")

df.j <- df.n2[df.o2, on = c("Loan Identifier","variable")
              ][df.j$df.old_value!=df.j$df.new_value]
```

which gives:

```
> head(df.j)
   Loan Identifier             variable                        df.new_value                        df.old_value
1:       960974101 Employment Type – B1 Employed or full loan is guaranteed                       Self-employed
2:       960959708 Employment Type – B1 Employed or full loan is guaranteed                       Self-employed
3:       960959806 Employment Type – B1                       Self-employed Employed or full loan is guaranteed
4:       960973707    Property Postcode                             LE4 8EE                                 TA1
5:       960974101    Property Postcode                             FY7 8HN                                 BB2
6:       960959610    Property Postcode                            RG18 4QS                                 BH9
```

Comment: Hi Jaap. Thanks for your reply. However, the melt function is not comparing exact columns. I am receiving results of differences where one column is compared to an unrelated column. For example, in my data the column "Originator" (in df.old) is being compared to column "Employment Type - B1" (in df.new).

Comment: @ConradAddo I'm not sure if I understand you correctly: Do you mean that the *"Originator"* column in `df.old` needs to be compared with the *"Employment Type - B1"* in `in df.new`?

Comment: THey need to be compared for like columns. The script works in the example, however in my larger dataset I get the result where "Originator" is compared to "Employment Type - B1" and not Originator.x to Originator.y and Employment Type - B1.x to Employment Type - B1.y I have the error "All measure variables not of type 'character' will be coerced to"

Comment: @ConradAddo Did you also try the approach with `reshape2` (option 1)?

Comment: @ConradAddo Can you add the output of `dput(head(df.old))` and `dput(head(df.new))` to the question?

Comment: Hi @Jaap, I have added the output. ID_KEY is actually [Loan Identifier].

Comment: @ConradAddo Saw that, but I removed that because there were no matching `Loan Identifier`s. To get that it is probaly better to use `dput(droplevels(head(df.old[order(df.old$`Loan Identifier`)])))` (and a similar one for `df.new`). Then add those to the question (and not to my answer).

Comment: @ConradAddo I modified the new data you added to my answer by giving both datasets the same `Loan Identifier`'s and added that to your question. The reshape2-method is working correctly (see the update at the end of my answer).

Comment: @ConradAddo I've added a working solution with *data.table* as well now.